# Filter a field (with regex) in a view

Tags: forms, views

I have a view with a field **Title** that needs to be filtered before being sent:

- Users fill a tracking number and press Enter
- This number is actually related to a node id
- If a user enter "123 123" or "#123123" it will not work because of the space and/or the # symbol

My first guess as a non-expert in Drupal (and coming from other CMS and PHP Framework) would be to add a filter to this input with a regex on it to get rid of all characters that are not 1-9. However, I tried to accomplish such a thing in creating a **Filter Critera** but it does not seem to be the solution.

Do you have any recommendation to do such a thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Filters" have certain meaning in Views. They are this little things that give "go" or "no-go" to result rows. What you seems to want is to **rewrite** user's input, not **filter**.

hook_form_alter I see in your tags is actually a good call. You can use it to append AJAX to onblur and make it rewrite field. Or you can use [validation function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#validate)

```
function yourmodule_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['input']['yourfield'] = _mymodule_sanitize( $form_state['input']['yourfield'] );
}
```

to rewrite it after user's submit, but before it is used by views. This function takes &$form_state by reference. It means you are allowed not only to read it, but also write to it, and your changes will be visible for all submit functions attached to your form, and will be used in next rendering of your form in case of validation errors or multis-tep forms.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer. I will try this soon and keep you updated.

Comment: I have created a `bartik_form_ID_alter` function in which I have added `$form['#attributes']['onsubmit'] = ...;`. It does the trick but I would like to do it server-side in PHP. Can you provide me more information to rewrite the user input using `hook_form_validate`? Thank you.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't make your example work so I finally managed to do it using function `THEME_FORM_ID_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { $form_state['input']['title'] = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $form_state['input']['title']); }` (example to strip whitespace).

This is very similar to your solution. Thanks for your help!